# How To Assign List Value To A Member Of Inner Model Class In C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, inner-classes, assign

```
public class User
{
    public string? UserName{ get; set; }
    public string? Password{ get; set; }
    public List<UserDetails> Headlist;
}

public class UserDetails
{
    public string? FirstName{ get; set; }
    public string? LastName { get; set; }
    public string? Address { get; set; }
    public string? MobileNo { get; set; }
}
```

I want to insert data from a table into the UserDetails class. I'm unable to access UserDetails List Columns when I access the user model.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow! What have you already tried to access UserDetails List ? Do you get an error ? Please include some code of your test.

Comment: Be sure add the set accessor for User property:`public List<UserDetails> Headlist{ get; set; } `. Then if still not working, pls share your code about how do you post the data.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
public List<UserDetails> Headlist;
```

Replace This With In Your Model

```
public List<UserDetails> Headlist { get; set; } = new List<UserDetails>();
```

and in C# you can write below code

```
User model = new User();
model.UserName = "abc"; 
model.Password = "1234";
//pass your list data to for loop
for (int i = 0; i < List.Count; i++)
{
    model.Headlist.Add(new UserDetails()
    {
        FirstName = List[i].FirstName,
        LastName  = List[i].LastName,
        Address  = List[i].Address,
        MobileNo  = List[i].MobileNo
        });
    }
return model;
```

Comment: Probably it is better to remove the setter from the list property, because you will never replace the whole list, you will just add/remove items from the list.